# Applying string function in column Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, sql-like

I'm using the latest Laravel 5.4

I am trying to make a simple query to search users by name. The query written for MySQL looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE upper(name) LIKE '%FOO%';
```

I'm trying to make it work with Eloquent. Things I've tried but failed:

1. `User::where('upper(name)', 'LIKE', '%FOO%')->get()`
2. `DB::table('users')->where('upper(name)', 'LIKE', '%FOO%')->get()`

Both fail with the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'upper(name)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `upper(name)` LIKE %FOO%)'

The query seems to fail because Eloquent wraps the  `upper(email)` statement with backticks (" ` ", " ` "). Is there a way to go around this issue or do I have to use a particular eloquent function to get convert a column to uppercase, lowercase, e.t.c?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `DB::raw()`

```
User::where(DB::raw('upper(name)'), 'LIKE', '%FOO%')->get()
```

It would generate query like this

```
"select * from `users` where upper(name) LIKE ?"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **whereRaw()** in laravel to achieve this :

```
  User::whereRaw("upper(name) LIKE '%FOO%'")
                   ->get();
```

Comment: Does this protect against SQL Injection or do I need to escape the passed string manually?

Comment: Nope. its nor against SQL Injection.