# Laravel Model get subpath using postgresql `subpath` function for ltrees

Tags: postgresql, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have the following table on a postgresql server named `breadcrumbs`:

`id SERIAL
path VARCHAR(300)`

With the following sample data:

```
id | path
--- | ---
1 | animes.like.hentai
2 | animes.dislike.hentai
3 | animes.like.shonen
4 | animes.like.action
```

And is modeled using the following eloquent model:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class Breadcrumbs extends BaseModel
{
   protected $table = 'breadcrumbs';

   // 
}
```

And I want to perform the following select without using sql:

```
select * from breadcrumbs where subpath(et_location_desc.path, 0, 1) != 'hentai'
```

So far I tried to use the following piece of code:

```
Breadcrumbs::where("subpath(path, 0, 1)","hentai")->all();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "subpath(path, 0, 1)" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "breadcrumbs" where "subpath(path, 0, 1)"...
                                               ^ (SQL: select * from "breadcrumbs" where "subpath(path, 0, 1)" = hentai '
```

Meaning that the first argument of `where()` method is autoquoted assuming that is a column instead of a function.

So how I can either extend the model's query builder or using the code above as is in order to perform the correct select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42734218/4706711) the same principle applies here as well instead of:

```
Breadcrumbs::where("subpath(path, 0, 1)","hentai")->all();
```

Use:

```
Breadcrumbs::where(DB::raw("subpath(path, 0, 1)"),"hentai")->all();
```

As seen in documentation you can use `DB:raw` in order to bypass the restriction of having a column name as fisrt argument.